# Unwanted Background and Auto-start Apps

Tags: auto-start, background-process

My android device is 4.4.2 and it’s rooted.

To manage auto-start app, I installed Clean Master and allowed it for root access. Also I stopped many apps that start automatically.

To manage start-up app, I installed Boot Manager Xposed.  Apart from these I installed other apps also for controlling auto-start and start-up app.

However, I see many unwanted background running apps and auto-start app.

Please go for screenshot. Whenever I close any apps, I remove them from Recent Apps also. And I keep Recent Apps empty/clean. However, most of time I see closed apps are still in Running Apps.

I do End Process for all unwanted apps manually every time from Running Apps which is ridicules for me.

[image: Unwanted Background and Auto-start Apps]

In screenshot, some apps like **My Airtel**, **Clean Master**, **Facebook**, **OneDrive**, **ET** News, **Practo** for health, **Fox** News, **Hindustan Times** News, **Flipkart** Shopping, **SuperBattery**, **Outlook** Email start automatically and very frequently. There are other user apps also that run in background automatically without tapping them.

Till the time, I don’t call/tap any apps, I don’t want see them in Running Apps and once I close any app, I don’t want to see them again in Running Apps.

Please let me know to control them.

Regards
GNS

Comment: Problem #1 - Clean Master, get rid of that malware! And like the answer says, you're trying to manage Android as if it is Windows, it isn't. Many apps will start their own services in the background, and if they are needed they do their job, if they are not needed Android tucks them away for later (figuratively of course). Messing with startup and background services using root level techniques can cause unpredictable behavior if you don't know exactly what you are doing. If an app doesn't behave like you want it to, remove it and find a different one or just deal with it.

Comment: Like him said uninstall clean master. Also if you want to stop apps running on boot use Boot manager (maybe xposed is required) aditionally you can use disable service to disable services you don't need but if aren't expirienced i sugest not to use disable service. And also there is force stop option but sometimes it isn't effective. Also delete this battery this battery that they won't make your baterry last longer but it will use resources. And disable apps you dont use, I doubt you use one drive so..

Comment: Oops i didn't saw that you allredy use boot manager but still take a look at my comment. Kaspersky? why do you need an ativirus?

Comment: Please see this new article 2017/02/10 [10 most useless apps and games for Android](http://www.androidauthority.com/most-useless-apps-android-749163). Most prominent, but specifically named in the list: Clean Master (along with quote-Booster apps, Anti-Virus apps, and Task Killers-unquote)

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn’t manage processes like Windows does. Properly behaved apps running in the background aren’t actually doing anything, they’re just remaining in memory and using no CPU or other resources. When you access them again, they’ll quickly open, as they’re waiting in memory for you to return.  If they were removed from memory, they would take longer to reopen as their data would have to be transferred from system storage back into RAM, in this way, a task killer can actually slow things down.

Android is made to manage apps automatically and intelligently for better performance! No need to manually stop them, they will be started again and again.

You should know that some apps needs their processes and/or services to run in the background!

Ex: Facebook needs some services and processes to fetch new messages or notifications.

So process killers will only drain the battery and consume storage.

You may need to read this article on [why you shouldn't stop a background process](http://www.howtogeek.com/127388/htg-explains-why-you-shouldnt-use-a-task-killer-on-android/) using task killers.

Answer (score 0):

Also it it just the fact that they are running, or are you more concerned about battery life? You could look into greenify app that hibernates selected applications or it can be manually triggered. It can take some experimenting to find out which to hibernate or not. If you are concerned about missing notifications as mentioned above.

Comment: I do agree with all and uninstalled Clean Master. Please look the screenshot attached.
You see, apart from system apps, there are many apps (be it news apps, shopping apps, email apps or other apps) that wake automatically & frequently. I close many apps manually. However, most of apps wake automatically. There are also many apps that do not wake automatically till the time I do not open them. And once those apps closed, there is no background process till the time I don’t re-open those apps. I want similar activities for all user apps. Please guide me, how to do it.